# Cómo implemetar código php através de js

Tags: php, javascript

Hola tengo un problema cuando incrusto mi código php a mi html, al hacerlo se comenta por automático, no estoy seguro si es por seguridad, pero aquí mi código js, resp es un arreglo que va imprimiendo el resultado de mi consulta:

```
var tbl = "";
for (x = 0 ; x < resp["success"].length ; x++){
    var htmleditar = '';
    var editar = '<?php if($_SESSION[\'usuario\']=="root"){ echo "Hola"; } ?>';
    tbl+= 
                '<tr alm="'+resp["success"][x][0]+'">'+
                  '<td>'+(x+1)+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+resp["success"][x][1]+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+resp["success"][x][2]+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+resp["success"][x][3]+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+resp["success"][x][4]+'</td>'+ 
                  '<td status="'+resp["success"][x][5]+'" style="color:blue;">';
                  if (resp["success"][x][5]== "1") { tbl+='Activo';}else{tbl+='Cancelado';}
    tbl+=         '</td>'+         
                  '<td>'+
                      ''+editar+
                      //'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btnAccion btnUpd" aria-hidden="true" title="Editar" alm="'+resp["success"][x][0]+'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>'+
                      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign btnAccion btnEstado" aria-hidden="true" title="Estado" alm="'+resp["success"][x][0]+'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myInfo"></span>'+
                      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btnAccion btnDel" aria-hidden="true" title="Eliminar" alm="'+resp["success"][x][0]+'"></span></td>'+
                  '</tr>';
}
$("#tbbAlmacen").html(tbl);
```

Todo se imprime aquí, la etiqueta del archivo es php:

```
 <tbody id='tbbAlmacen'>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>         
        </tbody>
```

En el Navegador me aparece como comentado, en donde lo estoy insertando:
[image: foto]

Tiene que aparecer solo echo("hola") solamente, ese echo lo cambiare por contenido en html, alguna solución? estoy implementando permisos por usuario para que pueden acceder a ciertas configuraciones. Estas configuraciones también son imprimidas a través de js.

Comment: coloca el texto involucrado como texto y no como imagen

Comment: No veo la necesidad, no hay nada mas que mostrar, quiero saber el porque me aparece como comentado.

Comment: es difícil saber el por que con un fragmento de código en imagen donde solo se ve el resultado del mismo, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Ya actualice la información, espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: PHP se ejecuta en el lado del servidor, JS en el lado del cliente, no entiendo bien la logica que intentas ocupar, imagina, sino lo entiende tu browser... menos en este caso yo.

Comment: Para poder utilizar eso, osea consumir desde un script de php, te recomiendo usar alguna llamada asincrona a tu controlador php y que la respuesta que te de este lo muestres en  el DOM con tu javascript.

Comment: Ya mira mi error, lo mas seguro es que borre este post ya que no tiene propocito, ahora trato de llamar una archivo php desde js para que ejecute unos permisos cada vez que habra una nueva pestaña, ya que si esta solo en en index no se implementa bien.

Comment: Tengo ese mismo problema, como pudiste resolverlo?

Answer (score 3):

Esta pregunta se encuentra respondida en StackOverflow en inglés.

Dejo el [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279901/php-gets-commented-out-in-html) y la traducción de la respuesta que es mas relevante en este caso:

> Para ejecutar PHP, tu archivo debe ser guardado con la extensión .php.
> También necesitarás ejecutarlo en un servidor. No puedes ejecutar php
> directamente desde tu navegador, ya que PHP es un preprocesador de
> HTML: tu navegador no tiene nada que ver con PHP, solo obtiene el HTML
> generado por el servidor.
>
> Entonces, debido a que las etiquetas PHP no son válidas en los
> archivos HTML, cuando el servidor no las procesa previamente, el
> navegador no las reconoce, por lo que las convierte automáticamente en
> comentarios, ya que no sabe qué más hacer con ellas.

Si no sabes como montar un servidor para PHP en tu PC, te recomiendo buscar sobre XAMPP, que es un paquete para montar un servidor sencillo de PHP en Windows.

Comment: Ya actualice la información, ese error no es mi caso ya que el archivo es php.

Comment: @CarlosEzequiel la respuesta de jme es correcta, para que tu codigo PHP se ejecute debe hacerlo desde el servidor, todo código PHP que insertes con javascript el navegador automáticamente lo comentara dado que no lo reconoce y no sabe que hacer con ese código.

Comment: Entonces como seria la manera indicada para integrar lo que necesito? es necesario integrarlo desde mi js.